# NHibernate & Temporal relationships enforced by the database

Tags: nhibernate

This must be a situation that other people have come across, so I thought I'd ask the question.  Have people implemented good generic solutions to the problem of representing temporal relationships within nHibernate.  This problem exists within a database over which I have no control, so please don't tell me the DB model is incorrect.  I can't change it.

We have a simple Parent:Child relationship, where the child's Valid Time must fall within the parent's Valid Time.  Put simply Parent.ValidFrom <= Child.ValidFrom && Parent.ValidTo >= Child.ValidTo.  This rule is enforced in the database, meaning I can't issue an UPDATE statement that will cause the records to violate it.  That is non negotiable.

Importantly it means that affects the order in which I write changes to the DB.

1. Expanding the child = 2 UPDATEs.
   i. Expand Parent.
   ii. Expand Child.
2. Contracting the parent = 2 UPDATEs.
   i. Contract the Child.
   ii. Contract the Parent.
3. Moving parent and child to date in future = 3 UPDATEs.
   i. Change Parent ValidTo.
   ii. Move Child.
   iii. Move Parent.ValidFrom.
4. Moving parent and child to date in past = 3 UPDATEs.
   i. Change Parent ValidFrom.
   ii. Move Child.
   iii. Move Parent.ValidTo.

So, we can see that the order in which the updates occur is very important.  We can't just rely on nHibernate's default updates.  Also, in some cases we need to do two UPDATEs on a single entity, where nHibernate would normally do one.

So, I want to get to the point where I can express a generic temporal Parent:Child in my domain model (probably using [attribute] decorated classes), and have some code do the hard work for me.

Has anyone run into this problem, and could anyone give any advice?

Please, again, bear in mind that I have no control over my DB schema and I'd like to write something generic that can be applied to my whole model.  The only caveat is that I only care about commiting objects that I have amended in memory.  So I'm not expecting to write some code to decide what the correct ValidFrom/ValidTo dates are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no control over the order in which NH issues update statements, the best course of action is probably to use `IStatelessSession` to do the updates "manually".

You essentially give up change tracking; you'll need to tell NH which object to update.